# System freeze on changing song (VLC, Clementine)

Tags: sound, vlc, music, clementine

When a media player changes tracks in a playlist, my system freezes for a second or two. If I am typing, this means that characters stop appearing on the screen and are delayed for a second or two, no matter the application.

Given it affects two different media players it suggests a system level problem.

System details:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Ryzen 3900X, 64GB RAM, Aorus Ultra MB
- OS and working files on Samsung 970 Pro nvme
- Media is stored on a Toshiba HDWE160 7200 rpm HD
- Have run self-test on the drive without error using gsmartcontrol

Any ideas?

Comment: A fully upgraded *bionic* (18.04) system will report itself as 18.04.5, so I'd check you have a fully-upgraded system (you mention 18.04.4 meaning you could be months behind on upgrades & fixes; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the date of the 18.04.5 ISO but installed systems upgraded before that date)   I would also likely check the health of the drive (esp. if a WD *green* etc as they slow down on errors to re-try preventing warranty claims)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry it was a typo,it's 18.04.5. I have run self-tests on the drive without error but it is quite old now so a likely suspect. Frustrating/surprising that it could cause system level issues.

Comment: Drive makes sell drives that don't have the slow-down feature (drives intended for servers), but they have shorter warranty periods than the 'consumer' drives that come with the slow-down & longer-warranty... You can check the health of the drive, if it's the issue using the drive's SMART (self-monitoring..... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)